# UFT - Sending table to function

Tags: function, hp-uft

I'm sending table object to function, At the function i want to select a row from the table,

But when i'm openeing the operations list of the object I don't have the table operations (like SelectRow, SelectCell...)

This is the function call:

```
Dim tableObj

tableObj=JavaWindow(BankName).JavaInternalFrame("‪XXX").JavaTable("YYY")
CheckTblFieldValue(tableObj)
```

And this is the function body:

```
Public Function CheckTblFieldValue(tblObj)

      tblObj.SelectRow "#0"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't have the table operations" do you mean they aren't suggested by inteli-sense or that you ran them and the step failed?

Comment: Both, the inteli-sense aren't suggest and i'm getting an error "The statement contains one or more invalid function arguments"

Comment: Try calling the function without parentheses, vbscript has weird rules regarding calling functions that don't return a value

Comment: I'm succeeding to enter to the function so the rerror is not in the call, I tried to call to the function in other way: activeMsg = CheckTblFieldValue(tableObj)                i got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've fallen victim to one of VBScripts particularities, when assigning a variable with an object, you need to use the `Set` keyword. 
I duplicated your code for Web and got the same problem which was fixed by adding `Set` try:

```
Set tableObj = JavaWindow(BankName).JavaInternalFrame("‪XXX").JavaTable("YYY")
```